# matplotlib bar chart title text wrap shrinks plot area

Tags: matplotlib

I'm adding a long title and long xticks to my bar chart. I'm using wrap=True, it works for the title but not for xticks, moreover, it shrinks my plot area, tried a bunch of things but nothing works.

```
    labels = [raw_data.iloc[question_location[index]:question_location[index+1]-1,1].values][0]
    men_means = [raw_data.iloc[question_location[index]:question_location[index + 1] - 1, 2].values]
    x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
    rects1 = ax.bar(x, men_means)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
    width = [bar.get_window_extent(r).width for bar in rects1][0]

    ax.set_title(raw_data.iloc[question_location[index],0])

    # Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
    ax.set_ylabel('%')
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels([textwrap.fill(label, width) for label in labels])
    ax.figure.set_size_inches(8, 6)

    def autolabel(rects):
        """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
        for rect in rects:
            height = rect.get_height()
            ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                        xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                        xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                        textcoords="offset points",
                        ha='center', va='bottom')

    autolabel(rects1)
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

[image]

Comment: `tried a bunch of things but nothing works`... What have you tried? Much easier to help if we know what you have already tried

Comment: I thought that the problem is in the ax. description, so I tried to use the plt.title and plt.ticks, but nothing helped. I don't understand why is the plot area linked to the title (so it seems)

Comment: Don't call tight_layout?  It is trying to shrink your axes to make the title fit on the figure, but of course shrinking the axes doesn't make the title fit...

Comment: removed tight_layout, changed title and xtickslabels to wrap=True, still ending up with the same results, the plot area shrinks and the text is overlapping